# Wordpress how to remove read more link from pages and not from posts

Tags: html, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site that has read more link added into content.php with ">Read more»

I want read more link to only appear in my posts and not in my pages. 
When i click one of my pages i see read more link which doesn't work and shouldn't be there.

**INDEX.PHP**

```
   <?php

get_header();

?>

<div class="container">

<div class="secondary-column">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar('sidebar1');// sinu widgets sidebar ?> 
</div>

<div class="post-content">

<?php

if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();

    get_template_part('content', get_post_format());  // dynamically include the post format - get_post_format() 
    endwhile;

    else :
        echo '<p>No content found</p>';

    endif;

?>

    <div class="pagination">
        <?php
            echo paginate_links();
        ?>
    </div>

<?php

get_footer();

?>
```

**CONTENT.PHP**

```
<article class="post <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>has-thumbnail <?php } ?>">


    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

    <p class="post-info"><?php the_time('F j, Y g:i a'); ?> | by <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID')); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a> | Posted in

        <?php

        $categories = get_the_category();
        $separator = ", ";
        $output = '';

        if ($categories) {

            foreach ($categories as $category) {

                $output .= '<a href="' . get_category_link($category->term_id) . '">' . $category->cat_name . '</a>'  . $separator;

            }

            echo trim($output, $separator);
        }

        ?>

        </p>

        <div class="post-image">

            <div class="post-thumbnail">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
            </div><!-- /post-thumbnail -->


            <p>
                <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more&raquo;</a>
            </p>


        </div>



</article>
```

**SINGLE.PHP**

```
    <?php

get_header();

?>


<div class="container">

<div class="secondary-column">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar('sidebar1'); ?>
</div>

<div class="post-content">

<?php

if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>


    <article class="post">
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

        <p class="post-info"><?php the_time('F j, Y g:i a'); ?> | by <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID')); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a> | Posted in

            <?php

            $categories = get_the_category();
            $separator = ", ";
            $output = '';

            if ($categories) {

                foreach ($categories as $category) {

                    $output .= '<a href="' . get_category_link($category->term_id) . '">' . $category->cat_name . '</a>'  . $separator;

                }

                echo trim($output, $separator);         
            }

            ?>
            <div class="overlay-con"></div>
            <div class="lightbox post-image">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                <?php the_content(''); ?>
            </div>  
            </p>

    </article>

    <?php endwhile;

    else :
        echo '<p>No content found</p>';

    endif;

    // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.  // COMMENT
    if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
                comments_template();
    }




get_footer();

?>
```

**FUNCTIONS.PHP**

```
<?php


function twentyfourteen_child_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'extra js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/extra.js');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twentyfourteen_child_scripts' );


 wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-3.2.0.min.js');


function learningWordPress_resources() {
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'learningWordPress_resources');



function get_top_ancestor_id() {

    global $post;

    if($post->post_parent){
       $ancestors = array_reverse(get_post_ancestors($post->ID));
       return $ancestors[0];
    }

    return $post->ID;
}


// Does page have children?
function has_children() {
    global $post;
    $pages = get_pages('child_of=' . $post->ID);
    return count($pages);

}

// Customize excerpt word count length
function custom_excerpt_length() {
    return 20;
}

add_filter('excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length');



function learningWordPress_setup() {   

    register_nav_menus(array(             
        'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu'),   
        'footer' => __( 'Footer Menu'),
    ));

    add_theme_support('post-formats', array('aside', 'gallery', 'link', 'image', 'video', 'status', 'audio', 'chat'));
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');

//add_theme_support('post-thumbnails','post-formats', array('aside', 'gallery', 'link')); // see annab errori
}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'learningWordPress_setup');


function ourWidgetsInit() {

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => 'Sidebar',
        'id' => 'sidebar1',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="widget-item">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
    ));
}
add_action('widgets_init', 'ourWidgetsInit'); // l2heb vaja et widgetit kasutada


/*
     * Switch default core markup for search form, comment form, and comments  // COMMENTS
     * to output valid HTML5.
*/
    add_theme_support( 'html5', array(
        'search-form',
        'comment-form',
        'comment-list',
        'gallery',
        'caption',
    ) );


if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {  
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
}
```

Comment: We are not here to fix your problems. You need to go look it up, and then actually try and not just post the code so we can do it for you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CONTENT.PHP add a condition

```
<?php if(is_page()){} else { ?>    
     <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more&raquo;</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Good Luck